# Test not running properly on jmeter servers

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I am running jmeter distributed test with 1 master, 1 slave through Jenkins pipelines. Pipelines to trigger jmeter-server.sh files on both the servers and i'm able to create object on them, below is the output for same:

```
Using local port: 4000
Created remote object: UnicastServerRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[XX.XX.XX.XX:4000](local),objID:[652e71b0:185345dcb07:-7fff, -3276995377179896203]]]
Starting the test on host XX.XX.XX.XX @ Wed Dec 21 11:08:27 GMT 2022 (1671620907500)
```

test is getting started on the servers as well but getting garbage value in the summary results

```
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using /tmp/resources/complete-test-plan-rework_Disrupt-SearchAPI.jmx
Configuring remote engine: XX.XX.XX.XX
Using local port: 4000
Configuring remote engine: XX.XX.XX.XX
Starting distributed test with remote engines: [XX.XX.XX.XX, XX.XX.XX.XX] @ Wed Dec 21 11:08:25 GMT 2022 (1671620905561)
Remote engines have been started:[XX.XX.XX.XX, XX.XX.XX.XX]
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)
Tidying up remote @ Wed Dec 21 11:28:20 GMT 2022 (1671622100532)
```

Below is the command used for triggering the test

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 USER@XX.XXX.XX.XX sh /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter.sh -G /tmp/target-file.properties -n -Ghost-name=pt -Gtest-data=/tmp/datafiles/users.csv -Gpng-file=/tmp/datafiles/screenshot.PNG -Gdownloaded-file-path=/tmp/target-files/ -t /tmp/resources/complete-test-plan-rework_Disrupt-SearchAPI.jmx -l /tmp/result.jtl -e -o /tmp/report -R XX.XXX.XX.XX,XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

Not sure why i'm getting this error, but if i'm triggering the jmeter-server.sh file manually from server this setup is working fine.

Below is the code for triggering jmeter-server.sh on servers

```
fqdn=${HOST}

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ServerAliveInterval=60 fesjenk@$fqdn 'sh /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter-server.sh'
sleep 30
echo trigger SUCCESSFUL
```

I'm only getting this issue while triggering the jmeter-server.sh from jenkins pipeline.

Can you please tell me what can be done now to start the test?

Answer (score 0):

The test is started, the problem is that remote slaves cannot send test metrics/results back to the master, that's why you see that 0 samples were executed in the summariser output.

It can be the result of incorrect [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote) in general and `client.rmi.localport` in particular.

Other reason could be some form of [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) blocking the RMI traffic from slaves to the master.

So double check your networking and RMI configuration.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: updated the client.rmi.localport=4010 in jmeter.properties file and also checked there is no firewall running on my servers.
If my test is running in background i should be able to see load my application but there's no load on my application.
can you please suggest next steps?